# Cross-encoding Integer.parseInt Java

Tags: java, parsing, encoding

I need to read srt files. I do this by common `BufferedReader`. These files can have different encodings. But I solved this problem by using `org.apache.tika.parser.txt.CharsetDetector` class. But now I have a new problem. When I read subtitles in Chinese, there is a problem with the numbers. So I define the encoding of the file and use it in its reading. For example, I read line with `1` and get String `"1"`. All is well, in String it looks like usual `1`, but when I send this String with this `1` to `Integer.parseInt("1")` I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
```

How I can easily solve it?

Comment: have you checked its ascii code

Comment: @Sundeep yes, it is 65279

Comment: `65279` is a [zero with no-break space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm) and not a `1`

Comment: @Lino before I wrote this question I also found this information, it remained a mystery to me.

Comment: @ProstoCoder you might want to `trim()` your inputs, to get rid off of such whitespaces

Comment: @Lino it doesn't work